# CLR Dll UI creating too many forms

Tags: c++, dll, clr

So I am trying to create a dll in c++ that will open a form when injecting it into a process.

This is the code I have (separate file from the files generated for the form):

```
#include "Main.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace::System;
using namespace::System::Windows::Forms;

auto FormRender(void) -> void {
    Hyperscanner::Main lpMain;
    lpMain.ShowDialog();

    return;
}

HANDLE g_Thread = nullptr;

auto __stdcall DllMain(HMODULE hMod, DWORD dwReason, void* lpReserved) -> int {
    if (dwReason) {
        g_Thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>
            (FormRender), nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    }

    if (!dwReason) {
        TerminateThread(g_Thread, 0);
        CloseHandle(g_Thread);
        FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hMod, 0);
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that for some reason it keeps creating forms when I inject it into a process, like there was a loop in the thread, but there isn't one as you can see. And when I try to call it normally, without a thread, it doesn't show up at all, which doesn't make sense because it's technically the same thing as the one inside the thread.

I am wondering what I did wrong and could use the help. Thanks!

***SOLUTION (by @hacksalot):***

The problem was that there were a lot of threads starting which would go trough my DllMain callback, so it would start a bunch of threads (didn't think of checking how many threads were being created for some reason).

To fix this, I added a global variable to make sure it only gets executed once.

```
#include "Main.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace::System;
using namespace::System::Windows::Forms;

volatile int g_StartOnce = 0;

auto FormRender(void) -> void {
    Hyperscanner::Main lpMain;
    lpMain.ShowDialog();

    return;
}

auto StartRenderThread(HANDLE& ThreadHandle) -> bool {
    ThreadHandle = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>
        (FormRender), nullptr, 0, nullptr);

    if (ThreadHandle)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

auto StopRenderThread(HANDLE& ThreadHandle) -> bool {
    if (ThreadHandle) {
        if (TerminateThread(ThreadHandle, 0)) {
            CloseHandle(ThreadHandle);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

HANDLE g_Thread = nullptr;

auto __stdcall DllMain(HMODULE hMod, DWORD dwReason, void* lpReserved) -> int {
    if (dwReason && !g_StartOnce) {
        StartRenderThread(g_Thread);
        ++g_StartOnce;
    }

    if (!dwReason) {
        StopRenderThread(g_Thread);
        FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hMod, 0);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices):

> You should never perform the following tasks from within `DllMain`:
>
> ~ Call `CreateThread`.

Also `FormRender` does not match `ThreadProc` callback signature and its invocation causes stack corruption. I won't even mention CLR stuff...

Comment: Everything @VTT said (there's a [lot of stuff you shouldn't do from DllMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain)) plus, be aware that `if (dwReason)` will test true every time a thread is created, not just when the DLL is first attached to the process. That may be why you see a "looping" behavior. Usually we see a more explicit if/switch to differentiate between process and thread attach.

Comment: You may be recursively creating threads there, since `DllMain` gets called for all loaded DLLs for each created thread if memory serves, with `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` for `dwReason`.

Comment: @hacksalot helped me solve my issue, but I can't accept his answer since he only posted a comment, will update the OP with the resolve

Comment: That's fine, it all comes out in the wash and I haven't looked at this stuff in a while so I was hesitant to commit to a full answer. Glad you got it resolved!